# Why does FROM_UNIXTIME in spark SQL return a different date/time?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can somebody explain why FROM_UNIXTIME(0) doesn't return `1970-01-01 00:00:00`. For example,

```
Seq(1).toDF("seq").select(
    from_unixtime(lit(0)).as("timestamp_1")
).show()
```

returns

```
+-------------------+
|        timestamp_1|
+-------------------+
|1969-12-31 16:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

The documentation for this function also seems to be a little off. Spark 2.3.0 [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#from_unixtime) says `1970-01-01 00:00:00` whereas the latest [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_unixtime) says  `1969-12-31 16:00:00`. Does it depend on the timezone settings for the spark cluster?

**EDIT 1:**

`spark.conf.get("spark.sql.session.timeZone")` returns `America/Los_Angeles`. So, I'm in PST currently and PST is GMT-7.00. However, `from_unixtime(lit(0))` is 8 hours apart from UTC, not 7. Note that daylight savings does not apply now.

Comment: I'v got the correct result on my spark 3.0.0 and my timezone is +9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of timezone difference-

**`spark=2.4.5`**

```scala
  //I'm in GMT + 5:30
   Seq(1).toDF("seq").select(
      from_unixtime(lit(0)).as("timestamp_1")
    ).show()
    /**
      * +-------------------+
      * |        timestamp_1|
      * +-------------------+
      * |1970-01-01 05:30:00|
      * +-------------------+
      */

      // Use UTC
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
    Seq(1).toDF("seq").select(
      from_unixtime(lit(0)).as("timestamp_1")
    ).show()
    /**
      * +-------------------+
      * |        timestamp_1|
      * +-------------------+
      * |1970-01-01 00:00:00|
      * +-------------------+
      */
```

### Update-1 by setting `America/Los_Angeles`

```scala
 spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "America/Los_Angeles")
    Seq(1).toDF("seq").select(
      from_unixtime(lit(0)).as("timestamp_1")
    ).show()
    /**
      * +-------------------+
      * |        timestamp_1|
      * +-------------------+
      * |1969-12-31 16:00:00|
      * +-------------------+
      */
    println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"))
    // sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
    // Please check offset which is -28800000 ms
    // 28800000 ms = 8 hours
```

Comment: Never thought the session has the timezone setting, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. However, it still doesn't fully answer my question. I updated my question to include my timezone info. I'm in GMT-7.00. However, my result is GMT-8.00 away.

Comment: please check `update-1`, its clearly because of time zone. If you have any questions related to `timezone`, you can ask it to the java community

Comment: https://databricks.com/blog/2020/07/22/a-comprehensive-look-at-dates-and-timestamps-in-apache-spark-3-0.html - very good description